# Adjectives for when there is a lot writing or very little writing on a topic

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, adjectives, academia

When talking about "a literature" or a body of research, what are adjectives to contrast a literature with lots of work, versus one with little work?

I'm thinking of something like "a broad literature vs. a narrow (?) literature."

e.g., "A broad literature addresses the question of when X causes Y. A narrow literature studies when Z causes Y"

Comment: *literature* is a mass noun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your choice of *literature* makes this difficult since you are trying to compare two quantities of a noncount noun. Switching to a count noun such as *studies, works, articles or papers* would make the comparison easier."Many studies address the question of when X causes Y. But few exist which address when Z causes Y.

Also, "when X causes Y", unless you really do mean what time it is according to the clock on the wall, is an informal expression that seems to clash with the register of the rest of the statement. "X as a possible cause of Y" may be what you are looking for.

If you are stuck with *literature* for some reason, just use it in the first sentence. You can have a broad/sizable/extensive/impressive literature. But as a collective noun, it doesn't make a lot of sense to use it to refer to a case where there are just a handful of studies. You can even use *literature* itself - There is an entire literature on ... ,but hardly any studies on ...

Answer (score 3):

If we're just looking for nice contrasting adjectives, why not use ***copious*** and ***sparse***?

The former means "plentiful" and implies richness, while the latter implies thinness along with its denotation of paucity.

Answer (score 0):

**Quantity vs Quality** - More references could imply a "greater breadth" of research but not necessarily as a narrow but "thoughtful" review could be more revealing. Both broad and narrow may require a description about what you really think and feel as a reader reflecting on these two studies.

Comment: I do not mean it's about quality or that either line of literature is better. Just there are more published pieces addressing the question of when X causes Y than there are published pieces addressing the question of when Z causes Y.